# Nifi 1.8 csv database ingestion

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way in nifi 1.8 for the PutDatabaseRecord to inform you at which line in a CSV file you have an error or the schema doesn't correspond ?

I'm interested in dumping big CSV files into a database, but I also want to log bad files and the line at which the error occurred.
I don't want to discard the whole file in order to log it.
I may ignore the bad line and continue inserting the good lines, but I also want to be able to log the bad line and the filename.

I would also want to send, if possible, a signal down the line and maybe take

Answer (score 1):

You could use ValidateRecord and send only the "valid" relationship to PutDatabaseRecord, then route the "invalid" relationship somewhere else like PutFile so you can take a look at the invalid records.